# angular2-counto inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to use the `angular2-counto` directive inside an `*ngFor` loop.
I know that I need a unique string in each instance. So

```
<div 
    counto
    [step]="30"
    [countTo]="myArr[0].Amount"
    [countFrom]="0"
    [duration]="2"
    (countoChange)="counto_0 = $event"
    (countoEnd)="onCountoEnd()">
      {{counto_0 | number:'1.0-0'}}
  </div>
  <div 
    counto
    [step]="30"
    [countTo]="myArr[1].Amount"
    [countFrom]="0"
    [duration]="2"
    (countoChange)="counto_1 = $event"
    (countoEnd)="onCountoEnd()">
      {{counto_1 | number:'1.0-0'}}
</div>
...
```

Should become

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myArr"
    counto
    [step]="30"
    [countTo]="item.Amount"
    [countFrom]="0"
    [duration]="2"
    (countoChange)="??? = $event"
    (countoEnd)="onCountoEnd()">
      {{??? | number:'1.0-0'}}
  </div>
```

But what can I use in the `???` as a unique param for each iteration of the loop? The `counto` directive needs a string param (I think). Attempts to use `*ngFor=let i item of myArr; let i = index;` and then somehow use the index in the directive don't work.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myArr; let i = index;"
    counto
    [step]="30"
    [countTo]="item.Amount"
    [countFrom]="0"
    [duration]="2"
    (countoChange)="i = $event"
    (countoEnd)="onCountoEnd()">
      {{i | number:'1.0-0'}}
  </div>
```

Results in `Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!`

Comment: `angular2-counto` hasn't been updated in nearly a year, highly recommended that you don't use a repo or npm library that isn't maintained because there's typically plenty of errors and plenty of difficult debugging.

Comment: @Z.Bagley the others I found had dependency hell :\

Comment: That directive looks like it never stops the interval on destroy of an instance. Plus the implementation is so poor that I wouldn't recommend it to anyone. The solution to your issue is simple: delegate the `i` value to a component that can store and mutate it. Or store them in the component of this template in a separated array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign `$event` to the `i` variável.
Try something like:

```
newVar[i] = $event
```